# The current path, index, didn't match any of these. http://127.0.0.1:8001/index

Tags: django, cmd

I setup webpage via cmd for Django.However, i had problem when accessing index page of 127.0.0.1:8001. I tried to update urls.py but still have problem.

Browser page error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/index
Using the URLconf defined in barry.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, index, didn't match any of these.

```
urls.py file:
"""{{ project_name }} URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from sign import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/', views.index),
]
```

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello Django!")
```

Comment: Can you add your apps, urls and views here??

Comment: Post your project directory structure.

Comment: Actually, i just installed python 37 and install django. I tried the steps to runserver (maange.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080) and update above URLS + views.


How to get the project directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking in **`path`** pattern. Confusing with **`path`**, **`re_path`** and **`url`**.

Have a look at documentation **[Django Urls - Path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path)**.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/', views.index),
]
```

Comment: Still now worked and prompted with below error in cmd.

Using the URLconf defined in barry.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, index, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Not Found: /index
[23/Jul/2019 23:46:25] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 404 1953

Comment: Paste your views.py in your question.

Comment: Added the views.py